# Meteor how to call a method defined in Meteor.methods()?

Tags: meteor

I am assigning methods to a Meteor server like so:

In bootstrap.js

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.methods({

        foo: function () {
            return 1;
        },

        bar: function () {

        // QUESTION: HOW TO CALL Meteor.methods.foo
        return 1 + foo;        

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: By the way, there's no need to wrap `Meteor.methods` inside `Meteor.startup`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The same way you would call bar: `Meteor.call("foo");`

If you are on the server and do not specify a callback the method will run synchronously.

**Docs for Meteor.call:** http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call

Comment: Ah yes, seems quite simple now, doesn't it? Thanks!

Comment: How does it work when i have parameters: `foo(param1, param2)` and want return values (at least error)?