# Meteor Oauth access other websites (500px instagr.am)

Tags: meteor, instagram

My meteor web-app http://meteor.app is basically a proxy to a number of other websites: i.e. http://500px.com, http://instagr.am

When a user search for a keyword on my http://meteor.app, I want my meteor server code to search http://500px.com or http://instagr.am
(effectively my front-end calls my server end-point http://meteor.app/search, which will do an Oauth call to 500px and instrag.am)
(I don't have a problem with oauth at the moment, using connect-auth atm)

I'm not sure how to create the http://meteor.app/search endpoint on meteor as everything revolves around the ORM/Collection and at this stage i don't use the persistence.

So do I use and customise Meteor.Collection class to query instragr.am end point or ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your client side code should be using: Meteor.call which will call a Meteor.method.
http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods

This method could update a collection of n rows of instagram and remove all collection rows and repopulate the collection on call to Meteor.method.

With a vague question though the answer is going to be quite vague :).

Madewith app is a good starting place:
https://github.com/meteor/madewith
This uses API calls and so on.

Comment: sorry wasn't too clear, i don't have problem with oauth (yet). my problem is how do I massage Meteor enough so I can query instragr.am http end point? and how do i create my /search endpoint?

Comment: Ah ok thought it was some new TLD :P

Comment: Meteor.method looks promising, will play with it :)

Comment: yes I can use Meteor.methods() to define an end point on the server and have the call call it using Meteor.call() as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343656/meteor-how-to-call-a-method-defined-in-meteor-methods